# Why does std::list have a max size?

Tags: c++

If `std::list` is a linked list then why is there a limit on how many elements you can have? Each element is a link to a new node and there's no limit on how many pointers you can have.

Comment: Well, for example, `std::list::size()` typically returns `std::size_t` so it wouldn't make sense to allow more elements than could be represented by that integral type.

Comment: There needs to be a limit since std::size_t has a limit and that's what list::size() returns, also memory isn't infinite...

Comment: @template_boy: be man! make your own implementation of list and omit max_size function!

Comment: @gaussblurinc Or just don't worry about the max size because it's extremely unlikely you're going to reach it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If `std::list` is a linked list then why is there a limit on how many elements you can have?

Because the `max_size()` function is a requirement for all standard containers.

> Each element is a link to a new node and there's no limit on how many pointers you can have.

Yes there is: the size must be representable by `size_type`, so a limit is that type's maximum value. There's probably no reason for it to be less than that.

Comment: I understand that that is usually how `max_size` is implemented, but it does seem pretty meaningless. Especially if you consider that `size_type` is usually `std::size_t`. The maximum of `std::size_t` is just the maximum size of an object. I could have a `std::list` of objects each of almost maximum size and easily hit the RAM limit before I have `max_size` elements. It just gives the *theoretical* maximum size as constrained by `size_type`. Seems a bit a useless.

Comment: @JosephMansfield It has more meaning for types like `std::vector` that lay out objects in a contiguous region of memory, because then the max size can't be larger than `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(value_type)` (and may be less due to padding).

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Indeed, if you know you're dealing with a list, it's not particularly useful. But generic code might not know the container type, and it's needed for some containers. For example, `vector` is constrained by how large a contiguous block it can have, and non-standard containers might have other constraints.

Answer (score 3):

> there's no limit on how many pointers you can have

There's a limit on how many distinct pointer values there can possibly be, based on the size of a pointer. For example, if a pointer occupies 64 bits in a particular implementation, then `max_size()` could safely return 2<sup>64</sup>-1. In fact it could be rather less than this, since each linked list node will be bigger than 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is because the standard says so:

23.2.1 Requirements for containers `Table 96 — Container requirements` p. 747 for **[N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)**:

> `a.max_size()`; `size_type`; `distance(begin(),end())` for the largest possible container

This, most probably, comes from the fact that in c++ algorithms separated from the containers. Algorithms are written as templates, so they basically duck type code, they expect some contracts to be fulfilled (i.e. providing some API). There are algorithms written for all containers so they expect whatever is passed as a container to implement full API, even if sometimes a particular method does not have much *theoretical* sense it must be implemented.

That said, *technically* there is an upper bound anyway so it's good idea to use it in such cases. Funnily enough, it is practically impossible to hit the limit you get from `std::list::max_size()` (i.e. you would run OOM), yet alone the theoretical infinity.